# Same form displayed twice on same page

Tags: forms

I have the same form displayed twice on the same page. It's the comment form . I put it twice on the same page . when I fill the inputs in the second one and I click on submit . I notice that the values that i've put appear in the input fields of the first comment form as well. Any idea why?

Comment: Drupal works out which form has been submitted on a page by an ID that is supposed to be unique. The comment module isn't smart enough to spot that its form has been used more than once, and it gives both forms the same ID, so really they aren't 2 forms but two copies of the same form, with the same inputs.

Comment: Thank You very much @AlfredArmstrong .. any solution that might help?

Comment: This module apparently can handle multiple comment forms, though it may not be what you are after https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_comments Otherwise you will need to write a hook_form_alter and change the IDs for the forms.

Comment: ah the form_id is directly accessible . Thank You again :)

Comment: I have changed the form_id but still taking it as one form and the html ID attributes of the fields are still the same.

Comment: I think it's actually the build ID you need to override but I haven't tried this in D8.

Comment: but the build_id is initially different . it is not the same for the two forms . for each form the build id consists of a different set of letters . So no need to change it.

Comment: So mainly I want Drupal to do the validation only on a specific Id which is the build_id . not based on form_id that is common to all comment forms.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue trying to print a webform twice on the a node. I worked around the issue by unsetting the `#cache['keys']` value for the form array. It prevents the form from being cached as its own render element, but the appropriate cache metadata bubbles up and the form is still cached with its wrapping element.

Comment: @sonfd Does this solve the validation error problem as well? If I don't type a value for the required field in one form , it gives me an error in both forms ! I just want the error to appear in the concerned form. Thank You again for youe valuable answer